# Loading all classes from a certain namespace

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to find a way how I could load all classes from a certain namespace, so I could check every class for a certain class annotation with the help of doctrine annotation reader. Is there a simple way to achieve that ?

Example :
I receive a XML/Json request. Within that request, there is a variable with a certain value ( Number = 1234 ). Now i want to find the class that has a certain annotation ( Number ) with the same value 1234.

I currently have a hardcoded array where i created a mapping between numbers and classes. But there must be a way so this will work dynamicaly.

Greetings

Comment: I think you'd better not to do this and use mapping. But you don't have only 2 options, you can find another way which is better than both.

Comment: any hint on another way ?

Comment: Can you be more specific on why you would do something like that? There must be an easier way to reach your goal.

Comment: I want to create some kind of backend system where you have one entry point. This entry point decides on the given number, you can call it "task-number" which function of the system will be called. Currently i map the task-number to a class with the help of an associative array. With this way i will have at the end a big array ... but i would like to save the mapping information within the class with the help of an annotation.